# Replacing some substring occurence inside a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

GIve me some advices concerning replacing substrings in a string.

At the input I have the initial string (it is a C# code always) and the NewName (**MyGood**) of the class.

the initial string:

```
using System;
using Meorfi.Core;
using Meorfi.ViewModel.Shared;
using Meorfi.ViewModel.Shared.Base;
using Meorfi.Wrapper.Base;

namespace Meorfi.ViewModel {
    public partial class ViewModel {
        public ViewModel() {
            Initialize();
        }   
     }
}
```

At the output It should be the following string:

```
using System;
using Meorfi.Core;
using Meorfi.ViewModel.Shared;
using Meorfi.ViewModel.Shared.Base;
using Meorfi.Wrapper.Base;

namespace Meorfi.ViewModel {
    public partial class MyGoodViewModel {
        public MyGoodViewModel() {
            Initialize();
        }   
     }
}
```

The question is: how to replace only the class name, and it's constructor.

Now, 
1) using string.Replace("ViewModel", "MyGoodViewModel"); I'll have:

```
    using System;
    using Meorfi.Core;
    using Meorfi.MyGoodViewModel.Shared;
    using Meorfi.MyGoodViewModel.Shared.Base;
    using Meorfi.Wrapper.Base;

    namespace Meorfi.MyGoodViewModel {
        public partial class MyGoodViewModel {
            public MyGoodViewModel() {
                Initialize();
            }   
         }
    }
```

2) replacing the  "`public partial class ViewModel`"  with "`public partial class MyGoodViewModel`" and

"`public ViewModel(`" with "`public MyGoodViewModel(`" (supposing that there are more constructors), will resolve the issue,

but if there will be some more blank spaces 
"**public   _ partial __ class *_* ViewModel**" or 
"**public ViewModel _*(***"
where '_' - are blanks, there will not be a good solution.

I want to do this in a very elegant manner. 
Maybe should I use Regex to do this ?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
Based on Andrew answer I solutionized the issue. (The solution follows)

```
private string ReplaceNames(string code, string newName, string oldName) {
         var classNamePattern = @"(?<=class\s)\s*\b" + oldName;
         var ctorPattern = @"(?<=public\s)\s*\b" + oldName;

         var updatedCode = Regex.Replace(code, classNamePattern, newName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
         var match = new Regex(ctorPattern).Match(updatedCode);

         if (match.Success) {
            updatedCode = Regex.Replace(updatedCode, ctorPattern, newName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return updatedCode;
         }
         return code;
      }
```

**Thank you all!**

Comment: Find index of namespace clause and do replaces starting from this index.

Comment: If it is always C# code, why can't you use the renaming feature of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y solution:

```
string patternClassName = @"(?<=class\s)\s*\S*";
string patternClassConstructor = @"(?<=public\s)\s*\S*";

private string Change(string source, string newName)
        {
            string changeClassNameResult = Regex.Replace(source, patternClassName, newName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Match match = new Regex(patternClassName).Match(source);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                return Regex.Replace(changeClassNameResult, patternClassConstructor + match.Value, newName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            }
            else
            {
                return changeClassNameResult;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try matching the space before as well, since all the packages have dots before them.

```
string.Replace(" ViewModel", " MyGoodViewModel");
```

Comment: @meorfi why wouldn't this work?  in your class and ctor(s) you always have a space before, otherwise it wouldn't compile - equally you can't have a space before in the usings

Comment: @meorfi Can you give an example of where this wouldn't work for you? If you have special cases that aren't reflected in the question, it will be hard to help you with any kind of regex solution.

Comment: suppose that there could be an entity (property, field) which's names starts with "ViewModel"... . This wouldn't work :) Thank boys, Based on Andrew regex, I solutionized the issue!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tools for doing such things (T4 i.e) but if you want doing something done and go on, try this:

```
var str = Regex.Replace(@"public
partial class    ViewModel", @"public\s*partial\s*class\s*ViewModel", "public partial class MyGoodViewModel");
```

And `str` would be `public partial class MyGoodViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Replace("class ViewModel", "class MyGoodViewModel");
string.Replace("public ViewModel", "public MyGoodViewModel");
```